# OAuth with LinkedIn

Tags: oauth

I'm currently implementing OAuth with LinkedIn, and running into some issues. Most of them I think I have already overcome, but there are two last issues left unresolved.

When I make the OAuth request I get redirected to LinkedIn's authentication page. Here, LinkedIn asks me if I autorize the app to have access to some info and it lets me know which info it is. If I change the `scope` parameter the list present there *does* change, so I guess LinkedIn is receiving that OK. That is, `scope = 'r_fullprofile'` asks me for my full profile, and `scope = 'r_fullprofile,r_emailaddress'` asks me for both the profile and email address. So far so good. Here's (part of) the code:

```
    if provider.name == 'linkedin':
        scope = 'r_fullprofile,r_emailaddress,w_messages'

    return { 'scope': scope } if scope is not None else {}
```

Then I authorise the app, I do get a response, but I only get some basic info. Always. This info includes the following, which I assume is the basic profile:

1. headline
2. lastName
3. siteStandardProfileRequest
4. siteStandardProfileRequest[url]
5. firstName

And that's it, even though I'm asking and authorising the info for the email address, for instance.

Then there's another issue, which is the user ID. Shouldn't I be getting it with the basic profile? I noticed I can parse an ID from the `siteStandardProfileRequest[url]`, because there's a parameter for that URL which is the user ID, but is there a better way? If not, is it safe to parse from the URL?

Best.

Edit:

This is the URL I'm requesting the profile from `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~`. Should it be something different? I've seen something like `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,email)`, but I can't find it in the docs, and honestly doesn't make much sense...

Edit: I'm now using the app settings in LinkedIn to set the default permissions, instead of passing them in the URL query parameters. The result is the same, I only get basic info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it really was the link. LinkedIn does need the `:(parameter_1,parameter_2,...)` part after the profile URL. This solved the problem.

Setting the permissions, like `r_basicprofile`, or `r_fullprofile` as seen [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-10a-overview#granting), is not enough. Also, [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) is a list of profile fields that can be requested.

As such, a profile request URL would look something like this:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,industry)

Hope it helps someone else.